# Display image in an collectionview based on string selected

Tags: ios, swift

I have following arrays of strings and images in `kindsViewController.swift`

How can I display all the images of animals if "Any" is selected from animals array and images of birds if "Any" is selected from birds array in a collection view

This is what I have done so far

```
class kindsViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var titleDisplayed: UINavigationItem!

var kind = [String]()
var kindImages = [UIImage]()

let animals = ["Dog","Cat","Rabbit", "Any"]

let birds = ["Hen","Kiwi","Parrot", "Any"]

let animalImages: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "imageDog")!, UIImage(named: "imageCat")!,UIImage(named: "imageRabbit")!]

let birdImages: [UIImage]  = [UIImage(named: "imageHen")!,UIImage(named: "imageKiwi")!,UIImage(named: "imageParrot")!]


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showOptions"
        {
                let indexPaths = self.collectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems!
                let indexPath = indexPaths[0] as IndexPath
                let AVC = segue.destination as! DisplayViewController
                 AVC.labelSelected = self.kind [(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

// AVC.imageSelected =  animalImages
        }
    }
```

The following is `DisplayViewController.swift`

```
class DisplayViewController: UIViewController,  UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{

    var labelSelected = String()
    var imageSelected = [UIImage]()

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 3

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
            as! DisplayCollectionViewCell

        cell.imageView?.image =  imageSelected[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well is quite easy doing this programmatically, you will only have to adjust the anchors of the images in the collection view cell, depending the the selection, you will call the function that sets 1 image or the one that sets all of them.

setting the image anchors :

```
class collectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell {

let image = UIImageView()
let image2 = UIImageView()
let image3 = UIImageView()

func setupImage () {

view.addSubview( image )

image.translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

image.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor).active = true
image.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leftAnchor).active = true
image.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.widthAnchor).active = true
image.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.heightAnchor).active = true

}

func setupThreeImages () {

view.addSubview( image )
view.addSubview( image2 )
view.addSubview( image3 )

image.translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

image.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor).active = true
image.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leftAnchor).active = true
image.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.widthAnchor, multiplier : 0.5).active = true
image.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.heightAnchor).active = true

image2.translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

image2.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor).active = true
image2.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(image.rightAnchor).active = true
image2.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.widthAnchor, multiplier : 0.5).active = true
image2.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.heightAnchor, multiplier : 0.5).active = true

image3.translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

image3.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(image2.bottomAnchor).active = true
image3.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.rightAnchor).active = true
image3.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.widthAnchor, multiplier : 0.5).active = true
image3.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.heightAnchor, multiplier : 0.5).active = true
}

}
```

Then in your display view controller add conditionals so that when the selected = any , then the cell needs to call the setupThreeImages instead of calling the setupImage. you will also need to set every image by calling cell.image = ....